# How can a python exception be logged to the debug stream?

Tags: python, logging

I want to log stack info from an `except` block with `logging.exception`or something similar - but I want the output to go to DEBUG, not ERROR.  The use case for this is that I want the fact the exception occurred to be reported on one stream, and the stack trace info on another:

```
import logging

try:
    raise RuntimeError('terrible horrible error')
except Exception:
    logging.warning('an exception happened')
    logging.exception('error occurred here')
```

This generates the output:

> WARNING:root:an exception happened
> ERROR:root:error occurred here
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 31, in <module>
>     raise RuntimeError('terrible horrible error')
>   RuntimeError: terrible horrible error

But I want the second message with the stack trace to go to DEBUG instead.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loggging.debug(traceback.format_exc())` I think is what you are asking for?